# how to set 2 actions on a form submit

Tags: jquery, sitecore

I see a few questions like this, but mine has a tweak to it. I have the code running directly from Sitecore so the only thing I can use is jQuery (no AJAX). The form either submits the values to its specified location, or it goes to the `retURL`, I can't get it to do both.

```
var data = {};

f.find('input, textarea, select').each(function(i) {
    var tag = $(this);
    data[tag.attr('name')] = tag.val();
});

$.form(f.attr('data-action'), data, 'POST').submit();
data['retURL'] = 'http://www.google.com';
```

I have some hidden fields and inputs and I was trying to call the `retURL` in the form in some way. I need the `data-action` to POST the values and then afterwards the user is sent to another page. So far I have only been able to get one to fire (last one entered) and not both.

```
<div class="jquery-form" data-action="https://salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://www.google.com">

    <!-- Then all the elements in the form... -->

    <!-- Then the submit button... -->

    <a class="button submit" href="#">Submit</a>
```

I also tried adding in a variable in the:

```
var retURL = "http://www.google.com";
$.form(f.attr('data-action'), data, retURL, 'POST').submit();
```

Comment: Why can't you use AJAX?

Comment: i already have a jquery function in place to take care of the form, so i need a way to make this work without using ajax

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: @Keith Why would it be a problem to first post the form via AJAX and then redirect the user to the URL?

Comment: was just trying to keep it simple, but if there is way to combine the ajax in, I guess I could try it

Comment: @SpYk3HH I tried this, the submit button doesn't fire

Comment: `$('form').on('submit', function(e) { /*  do the extra work here before submitting  */ })` then point to redirect

Comment: @Keith what is `f` in your code?

Comment: Why can't you simply add all the data together?
`var data = f.find('input, textarea, select').serialize() + '&retUrl=http://www.google.com'; $.form(f.attr('data-action'), data, retURL, 'POST').submit();`

Comment: its a variable in the beginning of the jquery that makes sure that the value is true

Comment: wait wait wait ... oh the irony ... "World's #1 CRM Solution" ... can't figure out a better way to implement simple Ajax ... lolz, sorry, just had to note the irony there ...

Comment: yes yes lol, its a pain in the but, that code only submits the data to the page, the retURL gets skipped

Comment: seriously though, use the developer tools, look under `Networking` tab, and see what you data submission string is. Make sure it looks something like -> 
`http://www.your.site.com/?tagName=Value&retUrl=http://www.google.com`

Comment: I used the link given in your post there, ran a test, didn't guess any of the proper tag names (i don't know what your form looks like), but i got a redirect to google every time i submitted the form, using the very tech i listed a couple comments ago

Comment: yes it goes to google, but the information doesnt get submitted

Comment: @Keith have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var form = $('#your_form_id');

$.post(f.attr('data-action'), form.serialize())
    .done(function(data) {
        window.location.replace('http://www.google.com');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change `action` property of the `<from>` tag as below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (objEvent) {
        // Prevent Form submission
        objEvent.preventDefault();
        // Change the action based on selection
        $(this).prop("action", $("select").val());
        // Now submit the form to selceted URL.
        $(this)[0].submit();
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="">
    Select URL for Form Submit
    <select>
        <option value="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</option>
        <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">http://www.yahoo.com</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit The Form" name="submit_btn" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a button.click() event and in that javascript function, make two AJAX calls to two separate web services that perform two different tasks.  You can run both of them simultaneously or wait for the first one to succeed and them run the second.